# run() in iron-router doesn't show page content

Tags: meteor

I am using iron-router in my meteor app and I have some strange behaviour.

My code is: http://slexy.org/view/s20lroT8EO

For some reason, after I get to the run() call (line 29), I see all the elements in the DOM,
but the page is empty except the top bar. Only after a refresh, I can see the content of the page.

I have a top bar in all my pages, so I use run() and not render(). I probably don't use run function correctly.

Is anybody experienced the same problem?

Thanks, 
Arshavski Alex.